# select not working in laravel eager loading after join

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This code works perfectly.

```
InspectionClaim::with(['claimType', 'inspectionClaimReviews' => function($query){
                        $query->join('employees', 'inspection_claim_reviews.reviewer_id', '=', 'employees.id');
                        $query->join('designations', 'employees.designation_id', '=', 'designations.id');
                        //$query->select('inspection_claim_reviews.created_at', 'employees.name', 'designations.title'); // when I am adding select function it returns empty value 
                    }])
                    ->get();
```

But when I use select function to specify which column I need, then it returns empty.

Comment: I may be unfamiliar with this syntax but is it fine the different between `inspection_claim_reviews` and `inspectionClaimReviews` ?

Comment: `inspectionClaimReviews` it is a function name and `inspection_claim_reviews` is the table name. And it is fine I think.

Comment: I think . It's best to checkClaimReviews
Create a relationship between the inspectionClaimReviews model with (employees and designations) and call through them.

Comment: What type of relationship is `inspectionClaimReviews`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is not related to `join`.

If you use `select` for sub query in eager loading, you need to **AT LEAST** include the **primary key and/or relation key** (depend on the relation type)

---

In your case, seems like the relation between `InspectionClaim` and `inspectionClaimReviews` is one-to-many, assuming you define relation in `InspectionClaim` class:

```
public function inspectionClaimReviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(InspectionClaimReview::class,'inspection_claim_id');
}
```

so when you do `select`, you should at least include this field  `inspection_claim_reviews.inspection_claim_id`.